# Start angle and extent values using Java's Arc2D give unexpected results

Tags: java, drawing, java-2d, ellipse

I am trying to understand the use of Java's Arc2D. Don't know how to calculate the start angle and extent when creating an arc out of an ellipse (not a circle). I want an arc of an ellipse with ry = 2 * rx where the start angle is at 45 deg and the extent is 90 deg. But instead I have to send a start angle of ~26 deg and an extent of ~127 deg to get what I expect. The included code generates an image with 3 arcs: green is a circle arc which behaves as expected, red is an ellipse arc with the expected parameters but unexpected results and blue is an arc with unexpected parameters but the expected result. Am I misinterpreting something here? In addition, at start angle of 0 deg and extent 90 deg the results are as expected??? Thx.

```
package example;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ExampleArc2D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int width = 800;
            int height = 800;
            
            BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D gfx2D = bi.createGraphics();
            gfx2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            gfx2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            
            gfx2D.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, 16));
            FontMetrics fm = gfx2D.getFontMetrics();
            gfx2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            gfx2D.fillRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());
            gfx2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
            
            int x = 5;
            int y = 0;
            
            int centerX = width / 2;
            int centerY = height / 2 + 200;
            
            int circleRadius = 200;
            int ellipseRadiusX = circleRadius;
            int ellipseRadiusY = 2 * circleRadius;

//            gfx2D.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 50));
//            gfx2D.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(centerX - circleRadius, centerY - circleRadius, 2 * circleRadius, 2 * circleRadius));
//            gfx2D.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(centerX - ellipseRadiusY, centerY - ellipseRadiusY, 2 * ellipseRadiusY, 2 * ellipseRadiusY));
//            gfx2D.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(centerX - ellipseRadiusX, centerY - ellipseRadiusY, 2 * ellipseRadiusX, 2 * ellipseRadiusY));
            
            double startAngle = 45.0;
            double extent = 90.0;
            Arc2D circle = new Arc2D.Double(centerX - circleRadius, centerY - circleRadius, 2 * circleRadius, 2 * circleRadius, startAngle, extent, Arc2D.PIE);
            gfx2D.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            gfx2D.draw(circle);
            y += fm.getAscent();
            gfx2D.drawString("ARC FROM CIRCLE WITH EXPECTED PARMS AND RESULT:", x, y);
            y += fm.getAscent();
            gfx2D.drawString(String.format("start angle %.1f° and extent %.1f°", startAngle, extent), x, y);
            
            startAngle = 45.0;
            extent = 90.0;
            Arc2D unexpectedEllipse = new Arc2D.Double(centerX - ellipseRadiusX, centerY - ellipseRadiusY, 2 * ellipseRadiusX, 2 * ellipseRadiusY, startAngle, extent, Arc2D.PIE);
            gfx2D.setColor(Color.RED);
            gfx2D.draw(unexpectedEllipse);
            y += fm.getAscent();
            gfx2D.drawString("UNEXPECTED ARC FROM ELLIPSE WITH EXPECTED PARMS AND UNEXPECTED RESULT:", x, y);
            y += fm.getAscent();
            gfx2D.drawString(String.format("start angle %.1f° and extent %.1f°", startAngle, extent), x, y);
            
            startAngle = 26.4;
            extent = 127.2;
            Arc2D expectedEllipse = new Arc2D.Double(centerX - ellipseRadiusX, centerY - ellipseRadiusY, 2 * ellipseRadiusX, 2 * ellipseRadiusY, startAngle, extent, Arc2D.PIE);
            gfx2D.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            gfx2D.draw(expectedEllipse);
            y += fm.getAscent();
            gfx2D.drawString("EXPECTED ARC FROM ELLIPSE WITH UNEXPECTED PARMS AND EXPECTED RESULT:", x, y);
            y += fm.getAscent();
            gfx2D.drawString(String.format("start angle %.1f° and extent %.1f°", startAngle, extent), x, y);
            y += fm.getAscent();
            gfx2D.drawString("even though it is clear that the start angle is at 45° and the extent is 90°???", x, y);
            
            gfx2D.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            gfx2D.drawRect(centerX - ellipseRadiusX, centerY - ellipseRadiusY, ellipseRadiusX * 2, ellipseRadiusY * 2);
            gfx2D.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            gfx2D.drawLine(centerX, centerY, centerX + ellipseRadiusX, centerY - ellipseRadiusY);
            x = centerX + ellipseRadiusX + 5;
            y = centerY - ellipseRadiusY;
            gfx2D.drawString("this is 45° as far", x, y);
            y += fm.getAscent();
            gfx2D.drawString("as the ellipse is", x, y);
            y += fm.getAscent();
            gfx2D.drawString("concerned!", x, y);

            gfx2D.dispose();
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
//            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("examplearc2d.png"));
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Found a way to get the angles but it was too clunky so took another approach. I used a clipping area to solve the problem. I solved my problem but didn't really answer the question. Won't pursue it any further. So basically I draw the ellipse but apply a clipping area so only the arc is drawn.

```
package example;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class ExampleArc2D3
extends JFrame {
    private Canvas canvas;
    private JSlider ryrxSld;
    private JSlider startAngleSld;
    private JSlider extentSld;
    private JSlider angleSld;
    
    public ExampleArc2D3() {
        super("Example Arc2D");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.add(canvas = new Canvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        southPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
        cp.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        JPanel labelsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        southPanel.add(labelsPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JPanel fieldsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        southPanel.add(fieldsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("ry/rx: "));
        fieldsPanel.add(ryrxSld = new JSlider(10, 25, 20));
        labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("Start Angle: "));
        fieldsPanel.add(startAngleSld = new JSlider(0, 3600, 0));
        labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("Extent: "));
        fieldsPanel.add(extentSld = new JSlider(0, 3600, 300));
        labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("Protractor: "));
        fieldsPanel.add(angleSld = new JSlider(0, 3600, 0));
        
        ChangeHandler ch = new ChangeHandler();
        ryrxSld.addChangeListener(ch);
        startAngleSld.addChangeListener(ch);
        extentSld.addChangeListener(ch);
        angleSld.addChangeListener(ch);
        
        setSize(1000, 1020);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private class Canvas
    extends JComponent {
        public void refresh() {
            invalidate();
            repaint();
        }
        
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics gfx) {
            super.paintComponent(gfx);
            Graphics2D gfx2D = (Graphics2D) gfx;
            Dimension size = getSize();
            try {
                int width = size.width;
                int height = size.height;
                
                gfx2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                gfx2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
                
                gfx2D.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, 16));
                FontMetrics fm = gfx2D.getFontMetrics();
                gfx2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                gfx2D.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

                double startAngle = startAngleSld.getValue() / 10.0; 
                double extent = extentSld.getValue() / 10.0;
                
                int x = 5;
                int y = 0;
                gfx2D.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                y += fm.getAscent();
                gfx2D.drawString(String.format("ry/rx: %.1f", ryrxSld.getValue() / 10.0), x, y);
                y += fm.getAscent();
                gfx2D.drawString(String.format("start angle %.1f° and extent %.1f°", startAngle, extent), x, y);
                
                int centerX = width / 2;
                int centerY = 460;
                
                double ellipseRadiusX = 200;
                double ellipseRadiusY = ryrxSld.getValue() * ellipseRadiusX / 10.0;

                gfx2D.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 60));
                gfx2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1f));
                gfx2D.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(centerX - ellipseRadiusX, centerY - ellipseRadiusX, 2 * ellipseRadiusX, 2 * ellipseRadiusX));
                gfx2D.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(centerX - ellipseRadiusY, centerY - ellipseRadiusY, 2 * ellipseRadiusY, 2 * ellipseRadiusY));
                gfx2D.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(centerX - ellipseRadiusX, centerY - ellipseRadiusY, 2 * ellipseRadiusX, 2 * ellipseRadiusY));

                gfx2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
                
                gfx2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1f));
                gfx2D.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 10));
                fm = gfx2D.getFontMetrics();
                
                // clip area
                Shape clipArea = buildClipArea(centerX, centerY, ellipseRadiusX, ellipseRadiusY, startAngle, extent);
                gfx2D.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 120));
                gfx2D.draw(clipArea);
                
                Shape oldClip = gfx2D.getClip();
                gfx2D.setClip(clipArea);
                gfx2D.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                gfx2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
                gfx2D.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(centerX - ellipseRadiusX, centerY - ellipseRadiusY, 2 * ellipseRadiusX, 2 * ellipseRadiusY));
                gfx2D.setClip(oldClip);
                
                double angle = angleSld.getValue() / 10.0;
                gfx2D.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                double len = 800.0;
                gfx2D.draw(new Line2D.Double(centerX, centerY, centerX + len * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)), centerY - len * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))));
                gfx2D.drawString(String.format("%.1f°", angle), centerX + 5, centerY + fm.getAscent());
            }
            catch(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        private Shape buildClipArea(double centerX,
                                    double centerY,
                                    double ellipseRadiusX,
                                    double ellipseRadiusY,
                                    double startAngle,
                                    double extent) {
            double radius = Math.max(ellipseRadiusX, ellipseRadiusY);
            Arc2D arc = new Arc2D.Double(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, extent, Arc2D.PIE);
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(-startAngle), centerX, centerY);
            return at.createTransformedShape(arc);
        }
    }

    private class ChangeHandler
    implements ChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            canvas.refresh();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ExampleArc2D3();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runner);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of writing the image to a file you can use: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));` so we don't have to load the image into an image viewer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Made changes to code.

Answer (score 0):

The API for the `Arc2D` class states:

***The angles are specified relative to the non-square framing rectangle such that 45 degrees always falls on the line from the center of the ellipse to the upper right corner of the framing rectangle***

Not really sure what that means or how that provides insight on how to calculate the appropriate angles to use to achieve your desired result

However, it can be demonstrated by adding the following code at the bottom of your class:

```
gfx2D.setColor( Color.YELLOW );
gfx2D.drawRect(centerX - ellipseRadiusX, centerY - ellipseRadiusY, ellipseRadiusX * 2, ellipseRadiusY * 2);

gfx2D.setColor( Color.ORANGE );
gfx2D.drawLine(centerX, centerY, centerX + ellipseRadiusX, centerY - ellipseRadiusY);
```

Comment: Thanks. Will use this to see if I can figure out how to make the calculation. Confirms my suspicion that some distortion was at play.